# Passing values from web page to c# application

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, webforms, webview

I have a C# desktop application which I wan to get register using a License Key by calling a web page (registration form) from a URL in WebView control.

I can pass values (machine id) to that web page in Query String form but upon successful registration how to pass license key and registration id back to C# application from that web page?

The flow of application is like:

1. User installs the desktop application and opens, which aks for registration
2. Registration form is hosted on a website url, which opens in WebView control by passing machine id in query string
3. User fills Details and License Key and hits submit
4. Software gets registered and generates a registration id which should be returned back to C# application, but how????

Comment: Ask the user to copy and paste the registration ID!

Comment: Use desktop application with comment line argument... and invoke the desktop application form webpage which will pass the registration id as command line parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Make a web service the Application can communicate with.

Make the desktop application request an URL on your website for the registration ID

Have the user enter the key given from the website in the application manually.

Comment: Avoiding putting fields on web application.

Comment: @seopower Care to explain that further?

Comment: He means having the registration form in the application, as far as I can deduce. And then transmit the values to the web page from the application (via webservice or web request for example)

Comment: Exactly what Allan said. I want to keep Registration form on web rather than on Application just to have control over the fields & validation. Because it will be used for more than 10 applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few common methods to do web-based licencing:

1. As Allan suggested, have your desktop application communicate with the website/api directly to request the license.
2. Download a license file from the server that can be loaded somewhere in the application.

   - As an option, have your desktop application register a file extension (`.myAppLicence` for instance) so that your users can open the file directly from explorer or web browser's download list.
3. Have the website generate a licence code that can be copied and pasted by the user.  This should be delivered securely of course - HTTPS, nocache, etc.

Of the three, having the application connect to the licensing service directly is probably the most secure and most difficult to circumvent.  The application can generate a fingerprint code of some sort that uniquely identifies the computer, and that code can be used as part of the key generation to ensure that the key is only going to work on that computer.  You can use the fingerprint as the salt for an encryption key generation

Of course you could also have a fingerprint code for the user to copy-paste into the website during registration.

Answer (score 0):

Different options have already been explained. You can take any one of the following routes.

1. Write a web-service in your desktop application that receives a callback from your website after registration. You can pass the callback url to the website during the initial request.
2. Parse the web-page returned by the website on successful completion of registration. For easy parsing, you can make sure your desired confirmation code / registration id is encoded inside some known delimiter text.
3. Require the user to copy and paste the generated registration Id in a text box in your application.
4. On completion of registration, ask the user to proceed next. When the 'next' button is clicked, send a request to your website and check for the registration id for given machine id.